# Match strings wrapped in square brackets not containing $

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a tag that's inside brackets and does not contain a dollar sign, for example `[title]`

I have tried:

```
\[[^\$]\]
```

and

```
\[[^\$]+\]
```

But it's not matching it correctly. Any tips on this?

Comment: It works, or not? https://regex101.com/r/A9XnHs/2

Comment: im using regexr.com to test, my code looks like this: https://regexr.com/3jiqi

Comment: Lookd good to me : https://regex101.com/r/sY1XYX/1/

Comment: @mickmackusa almost, is also matches src="[thumbnail]" /> src="[thumbnail]" /> (the full string not just [thumbnail]

Comment: Please update your post to offer more realistic input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include a `]` in your negated character class so that greedy matching performs as intended:

```
/\[[^\$\]]+\]/
```

To remove unnecessary escaping, use:

```
/\[[^$\]]+]]/
```

Pattern Demo:  https://regex101.com/r/ePmTRm/1/

*Note, you should not be using regex to handle html.